# Large function for unique values with criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

So need to find the largest number in a range with a criteria, and i have this formula:

```
{=LARGE(IF(range=criteria,values),n)}
```

but i need it to only bring through unique values!

Any input would be much appreciated!!

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want only the largest? If so then there is no need to deal with duplicates as it will return only one number.  Or, do you want a list of number from largest to smallest that fulfill the criteria and are unique?

Comment: Hi Scott, yes I want a list from largest to smallest.

Answer (score 3):

The newer [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can be used to replace the [LARGE function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/large-function-3688ad91-0b0c-43db-8ef8-825a5e5871db).

With your column A as the first criteria range and column B as the second, retrieve the largest number in column C.

```
=aggregate(14, 6, (C2:C9)/((A2:A9=E4)*(B2:B9=F4)), 1)
```

[image: aggregate_two_col]

Comment: Holy crap I thought I was reading a Scott Craner answer there at first!  I thought this question had AGGREGATE written all over it.

Comment: Never knew aggregate formula before this. Awesome. +1. Is it available in all versions or something new?

Comment: @cyboashu - ¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: So, it's been around for a while. I just never saw it before somehow. Better late than never.

Comment: Cool - nice function. but if i wanted to pull through 2nd, 3rd largest number, but ignores the duplicate values - so only pulls through unique ones- how would i do that?

Answer (score -1):

Cheers!

I am not sure I understand the issue; you want to find the largest value from array of numbers which fulfill your criteria? It seems the formula you wrote will work fine; the array IF will return array of numbers which satisfy your criteria, and LARGE(range, 1) will find the biggest value out of those available.

I tested it and it works for me.

Comment: What if the largest number in the list is 49 and the criteria is the number has to be even?

Comment: I should have mentioned I want a list from the largest to the smallest number of unique values